# Mongodb collection Size

Tags: mongodb

By default Max size of MongoDB document is 16 MB. However if my collection has an array of documents does the same limit applicable to that also.

For example:-

```
"Address":[{"name":"value1","pincode":"123456"},{"name":"value1","pincode":"123456"},{"name":"value1","pincode":"123456"}]
```

Here is it the case that my address collection cannot be more than 16MB?

Comment: Is `Address` a MongoDB collection or an array field within a document in a MongoDB collection?

Comment: Its a mongoDB collection which has array of jsons as value.

Comment: The size of a MongoDB collection is not limited to 16MB; they can be as big as you want. Is that what you're asking? It's still a bit confusing as you keep mentioning arrays. Collections have documents, not arrays.

Comment: ok... which essentially means that if `Address` is a collection then `{"name":"value1","pincode":"123456"}` are my documents whose size can be max 16 MB each but `Address` as a whole has no size limit... Am i right?

Comment: @JohnnyHK.. can you please post this as an answer so that I can accept the same.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Address` is a *collection* that contains *documents* like `{"name":"value1","pincode":"123456"}`.

Each document in the collection is [limited to 16 MB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-size-limit), but the size of the collection is not limited.